# How to set-up store with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to get my redux working with a new form feature and I am getting this error message now when I try to display my homepage. The index.reducer file originally had the auth and message reducers from the tutorial I used for my authentication was working fine previously so I haven't included the reducers for them.

Am I going about this the right way with the five reducers in the configureStore index.reducer file or do I have to put in a combineReducer function?

Error message

```
Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
```

index.reducer.js

```
export default configureStore({
    // combine the reducers
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer,
        fields: fieldsReducer,
        diveSchool: diveSchoolReducer,
        auth,
        message
    }
});
```

store.js

```
const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
    +  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

user.reducer.js

```
import {createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'user',
    initialState: {
        dives: [],
    },
    reducers: {
        // expects action creator to be called with a dive object
        addDive: (state, action) => {
            // append to the dives array
            state.dives.push(action.payload)
        },
        deleteDive: (state, action) => {
            // append to the dives array
            state.dives.push(action.payload)
        }
    }
})

export const { addDive } = userSlice.actions;
export const { deleteDive } = userSlice.actions;
export default userSlice.reducer;
```

fields.reducer.js

```
export const fieldsSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'diveLogFields',
    initialState: {
        current: [],
        region: [],
        diveType: [],
        visibility: [],
        diveSpot: [],
    },
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: {
        // picks up the success action from the thunk
        // [requireData.fulfilled.type]: (state, action) => {
        //     // set the property based on the field property in the action
        //     state[action.payload.field], action.payload.items
        // }
    }
})

export default fieldsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: `configureStore` returns store, and you are trying to create store with it. Pick one - either `createStore` from redux, or `configureStore` from toolkit

Comment: Cheers, so the error message i'm getting is coming from the reducers i'm putting into configureStore? do i need to use combineReducers inside the configureStore?

Comment: Yes, you need to use `combineReducers` function to merge multiple reducers into one

Comment: Inside `configureStore` from toolkit you [don't need to use `combineReducers`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore#reducer) - toolkit will do this for you. Error, probably coming from `createStore` that you _don't need_ with toolkit.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `@reduxjs/toolkit`. When you call `configureStore` function, it returns store. You are trying to put this store as a reducer into `createStore` from redux. With toolkit you should not use `createStore`. You already exporting store from `index.reducer.js`. Pass it into provider and you are set.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using the wrong method for combining reducer. For combining multiple reducers, `combineReducers` function is used.

```
export default combineReducers({
    // combine the reducers
    reducer: {
        user: userReducer,
        fields: fieldsReducer,
        diveSchool: diveSchoolReducer,
        auth,
        message
    }
});
```